# Hasn't vs haven't

Tags: grammar

Which one is correct to use

- she **hasn't received** the letter.
- she **haven't received** the letter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

She haven’t is wrong. 
If you refer to he, she, it you have to use has.
If you refer to I, you, we, they, then you have to use have.
If you hear he/she/ it have then the person speaking is either making a mistake either using some sort of slang (as a teacher once told me, even if I’m not sure this is correct)

Answer (score 0):

haven't is plural, while hasn't is a singular verb and matches the singular subject "she". 

However, this question is not well suited to the English stack exchange, please migrate it to the English Language Learners website, a community for people who are picking up English to help each other!